# How do I allow subscribe data to init first before meteor-react render execute?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I am using meteor-react, kadira:flowrouter and kadira:react-layout with remove autopublish and insecure and I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

React's render function execute first before the subscribe is done receiving the data from mongoDB. How do I let the data load first before render execute?

```
Store = React.createClass({

    mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

    getMeteorData() {

        var coursesFetch
        Meteor.subscribe("getAllCourses", () => {
            coursesFetch = Courses.find().fetch()
            console.log(coursesFetch);
        })

        return {
            courses: coursesFetch
        }
    },

    render() {

        let displayCourses = this.data.courses.map((data) => {
            return (
                <StoreItemButton key={data._id} title={data.title} description={data.description}/>
            )
        })

        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="card-columns">
                    {displayCourses}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figure it out by adding subscriptions function to my FlowRouter.

router.jsx

```
FlowRouter.route("/store", {
    name: "Store",
    subscriptions: function() {
        this.register('getAllCourses', Meteor.subscribe('getAllCourses'));
    },
    action (params) {
        renderMainLayoutWith(<Store/>)
    }
})
```

Store.jsx

```
Store = React.createClass({

    mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

    getMeteorData() {

        return {
            courses: Courses.find().fetch()
        }
    },

    render() {

        let displayCourses = this.data.courses.map((data) => {
            return (
                <StoreItemButton key={data._id} title={data.title} description={data.description}/>
            )
        })

        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="card-columns">
                    {displayCourses}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```